# check for partially filled rows and delete the rows that don't have data in them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have been working on a google sheet(sheet A) where the data comes from another sheet(sheet B) through importrange. In sheet A, column A contains all the urls, col C is the keywords and col F SEO keywords. I want to implement a function or an app script where for every url in column A, if the data is present in either column C or col F, that row should stay and if for url in column A, the data is col C and F is not present then the row should be deleted and the row below should move up. I am not sure how this should work. Can anyone please help me with the function or app script to be used for the same?

Comment: This could easily be done in Apps Script, but since the data is coming from an `IMPORTRANGE` formula, it might be better to modify the formula itself to just import the desired rows (empty C,F). In this case, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, or at least the formula you are using to import this?

Comment: Hi @lamblichus, the importrange formula is use is IMPORTRANGE("url","sheet name! range")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding your question.

So there is an empty B column between A and C column? If so put this in B2 `=if(sum(len(C4)+len(F4))>0,A4,"")` It'll see if both C&F are empty and if so return a value of blank instead of the URL. You can then just copy-paste values only that over into Column A and you're set right?

From my understanding you want to keep combinations A,C - A,F - A,F,C & omit rows where it is just A as the only value?

If so this should get it done pretty easily. Are you doing this on like 10k+ row sheets?

Comment: Hi Warden, thank you for answering the question. I'll be more specific. Col A has url in it. Now for every url in col A, I want to check  if there is data in col c or col d. If the one of them have data in it then we keep it but if for the given url, there is no data in both the column, then we delete that row and shift the remaining rows upward. Also, if for the given url, if there is data in both col c and col f,  then we combine those column in one column. The problem is, the data in this sheet is coming from importrange. I am not sure what app script or function I should be using

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to move around rows with data that was imported with `IMPORTRANGE` in SheetA.

What you could do is write an Apps Script code to move around the source data in the source sheet since `IMPORTRANGE` gives you a live overview of the data in the source sheet. This might be the "cleanest" solution. In the source sheet you could have an onEdit trigger sorting your rows so that rows with empty columns are at the bottom. Then you can use `IMPORTRANGE` to import only the rows where all three columns have the data you want. (Extra careful with using `IMPORTRANGE` in apps script please, especially when counting rows afterwards due to lag)

Another option would be to just copy the values with a trigger instead of using `IMPORTRANGE`. This wouldn't be "as live as `IMPORTRANGE`" though but it would be easier to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are importing some data via [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) and you want to remove the imported rows in which columns `C` **and** `F` are empty.

If that's the case, you could use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to filter out the undesired rows in the formula itself, so that they are not imported:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url", "sheet_name!range"),"SELECT * WHERE (Col3<>'' or Col6<>'')")
```

#### Note:

If you wanted to use a script, the source data should not come from a formula (in that case, you should copy the imported data somewhere else and work with the copied data, which would not depend on the formula).